# In Google Sheets how can I randomize the order of a set of values?

Tags: google-sheets, random, shuffle

Maybe I'm missing a keyword in my searches for a solution, but I didn't find what I'm looking for.
In Google Sheets I want to take a set of numbers and reorder it randomly. For example, start with the set [1,2,3,4] and get back [4,2,1,3].
Any ideas which function or a combination of functions may achieve this goal?

The entire process that I want to achieve is something like this:
I have a set of 4 fields. Their sum is fixed. I want to assign them randomized values.
So, I was thinking to iterate through this process:

- Create a random integer between 0 and the max possible value (in the first iteration it's the fixed sum)
- The new max value is the *last max value* minus the *new random number*.
- Check if the new max is zero.

  - If not:

    - Return to the 1st step and repeat - This goes on until there are four values
    - If needed the 4th value shall be increased so the total will match the fixed sum.
  - Else, continue.
- Randomize the order of the 4 values.
- Assign the values to the 4 fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SORT({{1; 2; 3; 4}, RANDARRAY(4, 1)}, 2, ),, 1)
```

or:

```
=INDEX(SORT({ROW(1:4), RANDARRAY(4, 1)}, 2, ),, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the first option and added a TRANSPOSE function because I need it as a row (:

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of app script examples as well

```
function DiceRolls(nNumRolls) {
var anRolls = [];
nNumRolls = DefaultTo(nNumRolls, 1000)

  for (var i = 1;i <= nNumRolls; i++) {
    anRolls.push(parseInt((Math.random() * 6))+1);
  }
return anRolls;
}

function CoinFlips(nNumFlips) {
var anFlips = [];
nNumFlips = DefaultTo(nNumFlips, 1000)
  for (var i = 1;i <= nNumFlips; i++) {
    anFlips.push(getRndInteger(1,2));
  }
return anFlips;
}

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}
```